# how to change html image src by j-query

Tags: jquery

view.aspx

```
<img src ="~/UserControls/Vote/Images/Arrow Up.png" id = "voteupoff" 
            runat = "server" alt ="vote up" 
    class="voteupImage" style="height: 45px; width: 45px"/>
```

i wnat to change it src ~/UserControls/Vote/Images/aftervoteupArrowUp.png when click on image i means

view.js

```
    $('img.voteupImage').live('click', function() {

 $('img.voteupImage').attr('src', aftervoteUp);
     }
but it's not working..
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('img.voteupImage').live('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', aftervoteUp);
});
```